# Running application one after the other process

Tags: architecture, mule

I have 6 mule flows( or the url) executing one after the other:

```
URL 1:http://myhost:port/process1  // takes 3 hours or more
URL 2:http://myhost:port/process2  // takes 2 hours or more 
URL 3:http://myhost:port/process3  // takes 4 hours or more
URL 4:http://myhost:port/process4  // takes 1 hour or more
URL 5:http://myhost:port/process5  // takes 5 hours or more
URL 6:http://myhost:port/process6  // takes 4 hours or more
```

Each process is executing based on data (may be mega/tera bytes of data) and execution time various based on data, each process is processing parallel( async).

Requirement is migrating data, code is done with Mule flow to ftech data and jdbc to insert the data. insertion jdbc is done with async call and for loops.

suppose If i run url1, not sure when it is going to end and If i put a logger at the end of flow, the logger prints before the process completes. If I make sequentially, browser waits for some period of time and expires.

At present I am running one url at a time and after finishing, running another url.

How do I make all this process should executes in a master flow, i.e one flow which executes all of six urls but it should complete one after the other.  I have made a single flow calling all this url by making sequential execution, but it did not work.

Problem i am facing is: Not sure what is the status of each url( completed/processing/terminated/error) and how do I make this process execute sequentially? 
Is there any other technology will help for me to do above tasks?

Comment: Are you implementing all these six flows in mule? Need more clarity on where all these six flow/urls are. Whether they are in your mule flows? or You are implementing six flows with each flow making a call to each of these URLs, in whihc case the URL are of an external system?

Comment: yes, All 6 or more flows are implemented as flows with http endpoints. eg: flow1/url1, fetches data from 2 dbs( oracle and sql server) and insert into destination db(people soft). Insertion of data takes some hours to complete.

Comment: What is the mule version you are using? Are the flows independent of each others success or failure, like If Flow 1 fails, the process should still continue to flow 2?

Comment: Mule 3.51, independent, but flow 2 should process only after completing flow1. As i had exeplained flow1 is a process which run async(scatter-gather)

Comment: What if flow 1 fails? Should flow 2 be still processed?

Comment: yes, it can proceed to flow 2.

Comment: After going all through the details the solution suggested by @RyanCarter in the answer below is suitable for your scenario. Plese let me know if you have tried it and if it is not working. We can figure out an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the `scatter-gather` router(http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Scatter-Gather) in Mule which replaces the `all` router.

You can implement sequential multicast by limiting the threads as mentioned here: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Scatter-Gather#Scatter-Gather-SerialMulticastwithScatter-Gather

Answer (score 0):

Try using a synchronous processing strategy and flow references:

```
<sub-flow name="process1">
    <!-- no need for an inbound endpoint for each process -->
    <!-- process 1 logic -->
</sub-flow>

<sub-flow name="process2">
    <!-- process 2 logic -->
</sub-flow>

<flow name="orchestrationFlow" processingStrategy="synchronous">
    <!-- any inbound endpoint will do to trigger the sequence -->
    <flow-ref name="process1" />
    <flow-ref name="process2" />
</flow>
```

You mentioned that your logger at the end of flow1 executes before "the process completes."  This tells me that the message processor you are using is returning before the intended processing has actually completed.  We will need to know the message processor that you're using to help with that.